# Scaling effect on element without moving the text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have a speech bubble with a text inside.  I try to hide it with the *`scale`* `effect`.  But when I do this, the text inside moves too i mean line breaks appear, while the `scale effect` happens.
How can I fix my text inside and hide it together with the speech bubble?

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
var splash=$("#splash");
        splash.html("This is a short text. Hide this text.");
        splash.delay(2000).fadeIn(400).delay(1500).hide("scale",{percent: 0, direction: 'horizontal'},1000);
```

CSS:

```
#splash{
    z-index:1003;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:295px 8px;
    width:180px;
    height:90px;
    padding:8px 8px 20px 8px;
    font-size:24px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#222222;
    box-shadow:4px 4px black;
    opacity:0.9;
    border-radius:8px;
    display:none;
}

#splash:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 12px 0 12px 100px;
border-color: transparent #000000;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: -100px;
top: 50px;
display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="splash" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top: 100px"></div>
```

Comment: It's working fine in chrome.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rutosuvoxo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Unfortunately it does not work for me, but I found something that helped me out. I ll post it as answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I just prevent line breaks in the css and do them manuelly in my text.
Now these wild line breaks will not appear anymore.

Text in javascript now:

```
splash.html("This is a short text. <br> Hide this text.");
```

I added to CSS this line:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```